# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: XML parsing illegal name character\r\n

Tags: c#, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I have a T-SQL stored procedure in a SQL Server 2008 database that I am calling from some C# code. The stored procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeleteActivityFromUserProfile](
        @profile_id int,
        @user_id nvarchar(50),
        @activity_name nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @profiles_xml xml
    SET @profiles_xml = (SELECT profiles from tbl_applied_profiles WHERE profiles.value('(Profile/ID)[1]','int')= @profile_id)
    SET @dprofiles_xml.modify('
    delete /Profile/User[ID = sql:variable("@user_id")]/Activities/Activity[Name=sql:variable("@activity_name")]
    ')

    UPDATE tbl_applied_profiles
    SET profiles = @profiles_xml
    WHERE profiles.value('(Profile/ID)[1]','int')= @profile_id
END
```

An example of the XML entries from the table, such as would be contained in `@profiles_xml` would be :

```
<Profile>
  <ID>20</ID>
  <User>
    <ID>BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783</ID>
    <Name>somename</Name>
    <Activities>
      <Activity>
         <Name>activity1</Name>
      </Activity>
    </Activities>
  </User>
</Profile>
```

This stored procedure functions as expected when I execute it in the the SQL Server Management Studio, and deletes a specified element from the targeted xml. However When I try and call it from my C# code, I get the following error:

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: XML parsing: line 1, character 143, 
>   illegal name character\r\n*

I am calling it from my C# code as follows:

```
public Boolean DeleteServiceFromServerProfile(int profileID, String userID, String activityName)
{
            try
            {
                SqlCommand com = odbchelper.SQLConnection.CreateCommand();
                com.CommandText = "spDeleteActivityFromUserProfile";

                /*add command parameters*/
                SqlParameter paramProfileID = new SqlParameter("@profile_id", profileID);
                com.Parameters.Add(paramProfileID);

                SqlParameter paramUserID = new SqlParameter("@user_id", userID);
                com.Parameters.Add(paramuserID);

                SqlParameter paramActivityName = new SqlParameter("@activity_name", activityName);
                com.Parameters.Add(paramActivityName);

                // execute query
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                sLastError = ex.ToString();
            }

            return false;
        }
```

I am not sure how the `\r\n` (which is a system new line character) is getting injected into the command. Is there a way I can check for that and strip it out from either the command in the C# or from the parameters within the stored procedure itself?

Comment: Side-note: you could write this: `SET @profiles_xml = (SELECT profiles from tbl_applied_profiles WHERE profiles.value('(Profile/ID)[1]','int')= @profile_id)` much simpler: `SELECT @profiles_xml = profiles FROM tbl_applied_profiles WHERE profiles.value('(Profile/ID)[1]','int') = @profile_id`. No need for a `SET ..` and a nested `(SELECT ...` - just assign in one step!

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware you could assign values in a select! thank you for that. Am I right in assuming that this could avoid potential errors caused when subqueries/nested selects return multiple results? not viable in this instance as ID is unique here, but in other cases.

Comment: yes, of course, this only works if your subquery really only returns a single result :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because I had not set the command type of the SqlCommand. I added this line and it fixed the problem:

com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;